# Re-run c# application after delay of 5 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

On clicking directly my c# application.exe file, i am running my application and its process in task manager appears if that process on certain condition kills my application stops. What i want is to re run the application after delay of 5 seconds by it self.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. That process is gone. What you *can* do is start a *second* process with you first, most commonly called a "watchdog" or "guard", to scan for your first process and if it does not find it, start it. It's not foolproof though, somebody could just as easily kill *that* process, too. It's just another layer.

Advice on how to implement that is far to broad for this format, I suggest you read some good articles on it, try to implement it and come here when you find yourself stuck at a *specific* problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although my answer might not be that helpful, and also this question isn't a kind related to coding issues, but I suppose, using ***Windows Task Scheduler*** might work out for you, as you can add various triggers to your application and repeat your task after any set amount of time.

Hope it helps. Thanks